# Заполнение datagridview по вертикально (C# winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

В datagridview можно заполнять по горизонтально, но как заполнить вертикално. У меня есть столбцы называется "Кабинка 1", "Кабинка 2" и.т.д. Я хочу сделать так. В первом столбце т.е. "Кабинка 1" должны быть отчет по первой кабинки, во втором столбце т.е. "Кабинка 2" должны быть отчет по второй кабинке.У меня только заполняется в первом столбце.

Вот код:

```
    void Dicplay()
    {
        outcomes = OutcomesModel.SelectAll();
        totalOutcomes = TotalOutcomesModel.SelectAll();
        room = RoomModel.SelectAll();
        barTable = BarTableModel.SelectAll();

        //Rooms
        foreach (var v in room)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(v.Name));
        }
        //BarTable
        foreach (var v in barTable)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(v.Name));
        }
        //TotalOutcomes
        foreach (var v in totalOutcomes)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(v.DateStart);
            //Outcomes   
            foreach (var r in outcomes)
            {
                if (v.RoomId == r.RoomId && (Convert.ToDateTime(v.DateStart) <= Convert.ToDateTime(r.DateOrder) && Convert.ToDateTime(r.DateOrder) <= Convert.ToDateTime(v.DateFinish)))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(r.NameGoods + ":" + " " + r.AmountGoods + " - " + r.AmountGoods * r.PriceGoods);
                }
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(v.DateFinish);
            dt.Rows.Add("Сумма:" + v.TotalSum);
            dt.Rows.Add();
        }

        dataGridViewTotalRoom.DataSource = dt;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewTotalRoom.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridViewTotalRoom.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        }
    }
```

Comment: dt.rows.Add("ст1","ст2");

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц, я не эту имел ввиду. Клиенту я создал отчет по горизонтально в datagridview, но клиент хочеть видет отчет ввиде экзеля. Например, в первом колонке отчет по первому кабинке, во втором колонке отчет по второму кабинке. У меня все отчет первого кабинка или пятого кабинка все в первую колонку заполняется

Comment: тогда Вам нужно записывать другими методами. Например сначала создать пустые строки. После с помощью dataGridView[i,j].value = ""; записать в циклах. Есть еще инструмент для работы с [excel таблицами](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.aspx) в c#. Также можно сначала данные формировать в коллекцию как вам нужно, а после отображать с нее.